# Angular 8.3.20 HttpClient refuse/fail while response returns 200 OK

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular2-http

I have create my `api/product-search.php` backend in `http://localhost/` like so:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
header("Access-Control-Request-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Request-Method", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
header('Content-type: application/json');
$myObj->name = "Test Product";
$myObj->qty = 30;
$myObj->sku = "test-p";

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

echo $myJSON; echo PHP_EOL;
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
?>
```

Using Angular `HttpClient` from http://localhost:4200/ like so:

```
getProducts(): Observable<any>  {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost/api/product-search.php`, this.setHttpHeader());
  }

  private setHttpHeader() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('Access-Control-Request-Headers', '*')
      .set('Access-Control-Request-Origin', '*');
    const options = { headers: headers };
    return options;
  }

ngOnInit() {
this.getProducts().subscribe(
  response => {
    // alert('Response');
    console.log(response);
  },
  error => {
    // alert('Error');
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

}

When I inspect the console I get the following error:
[Angular HttpClient Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhnVP.png)

When I inspect the Network Tab I get 200 OK like so:
[Browser Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tobl.png)

I can also curl successfully:

```
curl -i http://localhost/api/product-search.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 09 Dec 2019 15:16:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix) PHP/7.1.23
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.23
Access-Control-Request-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 100
Content-Type: application/json

{"name":"Test Product","qty":30,"sku":"test-p"}
Host: localhost
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
```

In Chrome:
[Google Chrome Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG1Ab.png)

It Looks like the call is being made successfully in many ways far as The Network tab, Curl and browser can tell, as of Angular http.js not so it ain't happy and I am not sure why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show error

Comment: do you subscribe to your response from server ?  getProducts().subscribe((value) => {//dummy})

Comment: @Alann  Yes updated it in question

Comment: Looking at the MDN documentation yielded [no results](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Origin) for "`Access-Control-Request-Origin`". Did you mean [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin), which can only be set on the backend/server, not on the client (as indicated by the previous error)?

Comment: Also, please consider copying and pasting your error log instead of attaching a screenshot of it such that it is more easily searchable and for users with poor internet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've accidentally set the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) request header as `Access-Control-Request-Origin`, which is an invalid [request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header):

```js
private setHttpHeader() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('Access-Control-Request-Headers', '*')
      .set('Access-Control-Request-Origin', '*'); // Over here! (It should be Access-Control-Allow-Origin)
    const options = { headers: headers };
    return options;
}
```

Also, take note that you can't actually set request headers from the client - these should only be set on the server/backend.

Comment: Thanks, But still failed after applying your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Found the missing piece of the puzzle. I've added the `pipe()` method chain on `getProducts` method like so:

```
getProducts(): Observable<any>  {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost/api/product-search.php`, this.setHttpHeader()).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`found fitters matching `)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Product[]>('getPosition', []))
    );;
  }
```

And That returns response from Angular Application.